# How do we explain the result of the expression (++x)+(++x)+(++x)?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, operator-precedence

```
x = 1;
std::cout << ((++x)+(++x)+(++x));
```

I expect the output to be `11`, but it's actually `12`. Why?

Comment: I would expect it to be 9... :/

Comment: @Charlie: Some kompilers might do that :)

Comment: I would expect a goat sacrifice before relying on code like that.

Comment: @Jurily wanted to know the behaviour of the compiler

Comment: I still would like to hear why you would expect the result to be 11...

Comment: Interesting. Just tried it down in the JavaScript console. Answer is 9 in Chrome.

Comment: @Nosredna: You are aware that this question is about the behavior of this code snippet in C++, not Javascript, right? In the language I just invented, `(++x)+(++x)+(++x)` makes the computer eject the DVD tray. But since it's not C++, it's not relevant to this question. ;)

Comment: I commented mostly because Charlie Somerville was expecting 9. It's pretty clearly been established in the answers that the result is undefined in C++. So now I'm wondering what other C-syntax derived languages do.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

We explain it by expecting *undefined behaviour* rather than any particular result. As the expression attempts to modify x multiple times without an intervening [sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) its [behaviour is undefined](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/misc-technical-issues.html#faq-39.15).

Comment: +1 I just tried this using gcc 3.2.2 on Linux, and the expression returns 10 (9 and 12 eat your heart out...)

Comment: Here is an imho nice sequence point description in the GCC manual: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.1/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wsequence_002dpoint-278

Comment: Then why isn't it a syntax error? Anything ambiguous that makes it into compiled code...seems like an oversight.

Comment: @Alex Feinman: forcing conforming implementations to diagnose an error adds an extra burden to implementers. Whether this cost outweighs the benefit for users is a judgement call. Often the C++ standard comes down on the side of not burdening implementers unnecessarily. Given the complexity of writing a C++ implementation this may be no bad thing.

Comment: @Alex Feinman: That's like asking why this isn't a syntax error: "MyClass& ptr = NULL; ptr->doSomething();"  Because no one who knows better will write that.

Comment: @Bill: it's not really like asking that, since your example requires DFA to analyse, whereas "multiple sub-expressions of an expression which modify the same variable and are not separated in the full expression by a sequence point" is at least theoretically diagnosable just by local analysis of the expression. But the way the C++ standard expresses the rule is "any allowable execution order of the expression" has no sequence-point separator, and implementations are quite reasonably not expected to reason about all legal execution orders.

Comment: ...and in any case even though this example with repeated use of `x` is not actually that hard to diagnose, if there could be aliases involved in the expression then it would be. Often half a job of catching errors is worse than none at all, since it encourages people to mistakenly think they don't have to think about that class of error because the compiler will do it for them.

Answer (score 12):

As others have said, the C and C++ standards do not define the behaviour that this will produce.

But for those people who don't see why the standards would do such a thing, let's go through a "real world" example:

```
1 * 2 + 3 + 4 * 5
```

There's nothing wrong with calculating `1 * 2 + 3` before we calculate `4*5`. Just because multiplication has a higher precedence than addition doesn't mean we need to perform *all* multiplication in the expression before doing any addition. In fact there are many different orders you validly could perform your calculations.

Where evaluations have side effects, different evaluation orders can affect the result. If the standard does not define the behaviour, *do not rely on it*.

Comment: then what is the use of operator precedence. i don't understand your example:
1*2 + 3 + 4 * 5 = (1*2) + 3 + (4*5)
no?

Comment: or a simpler example:
1*2+3*4= (1*2)+(3*4)

Comment: (1*2+3) + (4+5) == (1*2) + (3+4*5).  there is more than exactly one way to sequence the execution, such that order of operations is still preserved.  math is stateless, but if an operation affects state, you have to specify the sequence of execution more specifically.

Comment: @Dustin Getz: Technically, C++ grammar specifies that the expression must be (((1*2) + 3) + (4*5)) and not ((1*2) + (3 + (4*5))) but you are right that the calculation order could be 1*2, 4*5, (1*2)+3, ((1*2) + 3) + (4*5) or 1*2, (1*2) + 3, 4*5, ((1*2) + 3) + (4*5) or a number of other possibilities including independent parts being done in parallel.

Answer (score 4):

This is actually undefined. C++ doesn't define explicitly the order of execution of a statement so it depends on the compiler and this syntax shouldn't be used.

Comment: It's actually worse than just the order of execution being unspecified (which would just mean you don't know what the answer will be), in this case the behavior is undefined (so you don't know whether your computer will catch fire).

Answer (score 3):

The code snippet will invoke [Undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in  both C/C++.Read about Sequence Point from [here](http://www.angelikalanger.com/Articles/VSJ/SequencePoints/SequencePoints.html).

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion

```
cout<<((++x)+(++x)+(++x));
```

compiler first run prefix ++x so value of x becomes

x=2

---

now by ++x, x will become

x=3

---

after ++x

x=4

---

Now its time to add values of x

x+x+x=4+4+4

x+x+x=12

Comment: Opinions are not answers. It is also in contradiction with what is already marked as the correct answer: undefined

Comment: I only told that above expression does not mean 2+3+4 because value of x is changed first then it is added. means 2+3+4 is not answer but it actually add like this 4+4+4.

Comment: Though the other answers might be technically appropriate in a general sense, this is the only answer that actually explains why 12 is a logical result.  So +1 for explaining that, even if this is a weird pattern that shouldn't be followed in practice.  In my eyes, this in conjunction with the other answers is what's really required to completely answer the original question.  Explaining why this isn't the only way it could be interpreted would also be a nice addition to lead into the undefined behavior aspect.