# ++i + ++i + ++i in Java vs C

Tags: java, c, undefined-behavior, operator-precedence

```
int i=2;
i = ++i + ++i + ++i;
```

Which is more correct? Java's result of 12 or C = 13. Or if not a matter of correctness, please elaborate.

Comment: That's odd; when I compile it in C my compiler dances like an undefined chicken.

Comment: why -1 ? Is this not a valid question?  Anyhow @Strilanc, what compiler are you using?

Comment: If you *really* see that in your code, I think it's better to refactor that!!

Comment: It is a trivial example because I just want to know how things work.

Comment: Duplicate of [How do we explain the result of the expression (++x)+(++x)+(++x)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525187/how-do-we-explain-the-result-of-the-expression-xxx) Why are these questions asked so often?

Comment: @dalle - not really, different languages will handle this differently.

Comment: @dalle, that question doesn't even mention Java, which is quite different in this regard.

Comment: -1 from me, too, for asking a FAQ. Any book you'll ever read about these operators make it very clear that mixing multiple post/pre increment/decrement operators is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @dalle: I think that C's expression evaluation rules, in particular the sequence point rule, are genuinely surprising to many people at a certain stage of learning the language. Especially coming from Java, where it is all defined. So, a lot of people ask about it, and often (not this time) a few people give very wrong answers. As for why it's surprising - a little knowledge is a dangerous thing, so maybe people reach a fairly natural mental model of "how compilers do arithmetic" which simply doesn't take account of how C compilers *optimize* arithmetic, and so is wrong.

Comment: Also, even I find it slightly surprising that `++i + ++i` is undefined behavior, but is not a breach of language constraints. More to the point is that `int incboth(int *p, int *q) { return ++*p + ++*q; }` is fine if the caller passes in different values for p and q, and not fine if called with the same pointer value twice. Clearly the compiler cannot help you with that one (although C99 `restrict` at least indicates the intent), which is why the sequence point rule cannot be entirely expressed as a language constraint.

Comment: -1 for yet another repeat of the most frequent duplicate question. Can't SO implement some kind of duplicate warning when it sees too many ++'s close together or something?

Comment: @Steve Jessop:  There's nothing stopping implementations from issuing warning messages.

Comment: @PP:  Any book you read about C or C++ will point out that this is an error.  The poster also asked about Java, which is an entirely different question.

Comment: Oh, and also:  If you have to ask about the meaning of an expression on Stack Overflow or similar site, don't put it in a program.  We don't want the next person working on your program to have to come here to understand your program.

Comment: @David: sure, but there's also nothing stopping compilers from issuing a warning for assigning to const, but that's a language constraint violation. I said I was only "slightly" surprised - I guess it's just unnecessarily complicated to define a reasonable constraint.

Comment: The question belongs closed. It's not a question about the Java behavior of this expression, but a question about why the C behavior does not match the Java behavior, and it's simply yet another case of being ignorant of sequence points like every other duplicate of this topic.

Comment: sorry for being ignorant

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is nothing like more correct. It is actually undefined and its called Sequence Point Error. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point

Comment: Thank you, I'm enlightened by the term Sequence Point Error.

Comment: It's well-defined in Java.

Answer (score 29):

Java guarantees ([§15.7.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.1)) that it will be evaluated left-to-right, giving 12.  Specifically, `++` has higher precedence that `+`.  So it first binds those, then it associates the addition operations left to right

```
i = (((++i) + (++i)) + (++i));
```

§15.7.1 says the left operand is evaluated first, and [§15.7.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.2) says both operands are evaluated before the operation.  So it evaluates like:

```
i = (((++i) + (++i)) + (++i));
i = ((3 + (++i)) + (++i)); // i = 3;
i = ((3 + 4) + (++i)); // i = 4;
i = (7 + (++i)); // i = 4;
i = (7 + 5); // i = 5;
i = 12;
```

In C, it is undefined behavior to modify a variable twice without a sequence point in between.

Comment: A small question - is left-to-right really needed here? In this example, can another order give a different result? I suppose it's more relevant to statements like `i = (i*=2) + (i*=3) + (i*=4);`, where order matters.

Comment: @Kobi, not really, but I hope explaining simpler cases helps people work up to more complex ones.

Comment: Change it to `++i - ++i - ++i` and left-to-right order becomes very important.

Comment: Shouldn't the step after `((3 + 4) + (++i))` be `((3 + 4) + 5)`? Since `++` has higher precedence than `+`?

Comment: @config, it's important to distinguish between precedence and order of evaluation.  The precedence basically determines where the simulated parentheses are put; order of evaluation is the sequence of actual computations.  Order of evaluation is in [§15.7](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.7).  Because of [§15.7.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.7.1) the left operand `(3 + 4)` must be evaluated before the right operand `(++i)` (of the outer +).

Answer (score 7):

The Java result makes sense to me because the operators give the result you would expect, but no serious program should contain a statement like this.

Answer (score 5):

In C this is undefined behavior. There is no correct behavior.