# Precedence of increment and decrement opreators in C++

Tags: c++, increment, decrement

I tried this on my gcc:

```
int a=1;
cout<<(--a)--;
```

and the output is 0; but change it to

```
cout<<--(a--);
```

results in an error (lvalue required as decrement operand). Could someone enlighten me about this?

Thanks!

Comment: **Don't just tell us you have an error, tell us what that error is!** (If you had, I'd have upvoted, but without that, it can't be a good question.)

Comment: Now that I take a look upon it, it says "lvalue required as decrement operand".

Comment: @Fred Nurk  Thanks for the comment. Edited already:)

Comment: _Always_ read the errors, and if you don't understand it look it up. The first page returned by copy-and-paste-ing that error text into Google has the answer to your question.

Comment: This is one of the most commonly asked class of questions on SO.  Start at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525187/how-do-we-explain-the-result-of-the-expression-xxx and see the "linked" sidebar, you'll see many with lots of good answers.

Comment: @Fred Nurk  Great link! THX :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both versions of `++` require lvalues as arguments, but the prefix version returns an lvalue as an argument, while the postfix version returns an rvalue.

Either way, you can't modify the same object twice between sequence points, so your "working" example invokes undefind behavior. The output can be whatever the compiler feels like doing. If you're just asking out of curiosity that's fine, but if this is relevant to your actual code you might be doing something wrong.

Comment: hang on a tick, if prefix increment doesn't count as a sequence point, why does it return an lvalue? (Note it doesn't in C)

Comment: @Random832 - Because there's only about seven sequence points defined in C. None of the assignment operators are sequence points either. If you ask "why" it'll probably be "because that requires more overhead and makes the code potentially slower."

Comment: None of them return lvalues in C, though. What's the point of an lvalue you can't assign to?

Comment: @Random832 - Yes they do. `(a = b) = c` compiles in G++. (Plain GCC actually emits an error that I don't know how to disable, which is a Good Thing, but it's still syntactically valid.)

Answer (score 8):

predecrement `--a` decrements `a`, and then gives you back `a` itself.  So you can then go on to modify it any way you want, including a postdecrement.

postdecrement `a--` decrements `a` but gives you back a's value before the decrement.  It's essentially giving you a copy of `a`.  But you cannot then predecrement this copy.  It's not an lvalue, so there's nothing to decrement.  That's why it's an error.

Think of predecrement as returning a reference to `a`, and postdecrement as returning by constant value.

Comment: "So you can then go on to modify it any way you want, including a postdecrement." Err, you _can_ but it's undefined behavior to do so.

Comment: @Chris, true, but it's ok to do in C++0x

Comment: When C++0x comes out it'll still be a bad idea to write `++++++++x` in your code regardless of whether it's UB or not.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> (--a)--
> ```

This is undefined behavior, as you modify the same object twice without an intervening sequence point.  The compiler is not required to report when you invoke UB – it *can't* even detect UB in many situations.  But if you turn on the right warnings (and you should look at what yours provides), it may be able to, sometimes.

> ```
> --(a--)
> ```

Prefix decrement requires an lvalue, but postfix decrement returns an rvalue.  This is an error that, unlike undefined behavior, the compiler is *required* to report.